# Creating counts for continuous variable to be grouped by another variable

Tags: r

I have a dataset of 65000 rows. Here is a glimpse of the same for explanation purposes.

```
state <- c("TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "WI", "WI", "WI", "WI", "WI")

centrac <- c("TX01", "TX02", "TX03", "TX04", "TX05", "TX06", "TX07", "TX08", "CA01", "CA02", "CA03", "CA04", "CA05", "CA06", "CA07", "WI01", "WI02", "WI03", "WI04", "WI05")

pov <- c(48.00, 35.00, 7.04, 18.24, 28.45, 43.76, 3.91, 68.47, 5.29, 11.82, 27.89, 30.13, 17.63, 7.71, 3.45, 56.38, 2.17, 21.09, 23.56, 45.67)

df <- data.frame(state, centrac, pov)
print(df)

   state    centrac   pov
1     TX    TX01      48.00
2     TX    TX02      35.00
3     TX    TX03       7.04
4     TX    TX04      18.24
5     TX    TX05      28.45
6     TX    TX06      43.76
7     TX    TX07       3.91
8     TX    TX08      68.47
9     CA    CA01       5.29
10    CA    CA02      11.82
11    CA    CA03      27.89
12    CA    CA04      30.13
13    CA    CA05      17.63
14    CA    CA06       7.71
15    CA    CA07       3.45
16    WI    WI01      56.38
17    WI    WI02       2.17
18    WI    WI03      21.09
19    WI    WI04      23.56
20    WI    WI05      45.67
```

First, I need to find out the number of `centrac` by counts for `pov` in 5 ranges:

Less than 10 (Very Low Poverty)

10-20 (Low Poverty)

20-30 (Medium Poverty)

30-40 (High Poverty)

More than 40 (Very High Poverty)

And then group these counts by `state`, so that I get the following table:

```
Number of Census Tracts by Poverty

State     Very Low Poverty    Low Poverty   Medium Poverty   High Poverty   Very High Poverty
            (Less than 10)       (10-20)        (20-30)         (30-40)       (More than 40)
TX                2                 1             1                 1               3
CA                3                 2             1                 1               0
WI                1                 0             2                 0               2
```

I am able to use `group_by` to get the data arranged by `state`, however I am stuck at the first part.

Much appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cut()` to create bins from a continuous variable.

```
df[["pov_level"]] <- cut(
  df$pov, 
  breaks = c(-Inf, 10, 20, 30, 40, Inf),
  labels = c(
    "Less than 10 (Very Low Poverty)",
    "10-20 (Low Poverty)",
    "20-30 (Medium Poverty)",
    "30-40 (High Poverty)",
    "More than 40 (Very High Poverty)"
  )
)

table(df$state, df$pov_level)
#    Less than 10 (Very Low Poverty) 10-20 (Low Poverty) 20-30 (Medium Poverty)
# CA                               3                   2                      1
# TX                               2                   1                      1
# WI                               1                   0                      2
# 
#    30-40 (High Poverty) More than 40 (Very High Poverty)
# CA                    1                                0
# TX                    1                                3
# WI                    0                                2
```

Comment: Awesome! The only change I needed to make while using the code on my actual/larger dataset is to use ```df[["pov_level"]] <- cut(
  *df$pov*, 
  breaks = ``` otherwise I was getting error message as Object not found. In the event of needing to convert these numbers into percent, how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Still by cut(), another option to take count(aggregate()):

```
state <- c("TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "WI", "WI", "WI", "WI", "WI")

centrac <- c("TX01", "TX02", "TX03", "TX04", "TX05", "TX06", "TX07", "TX08", "CA01", "CA02", "CA03", "CA04", "CA05", "CA06", "CA07", "WI01", "WI02", "WI03", "WI04", "WI05")

pov <- c(48.00, 35.00, 7.04, 18.24, 28.45, 43.76, 3.91, 68.47, 5.29, 11.82, 27.89, 30.13, 17.63, 7.71, 3.45, 56.38, 2.17, 21.09, 23.56, 45.67)

df <- data.frame(state, centrac, pov)

cut_breaks = breaks = c(0,10,20,30,40,Inf)

cut_labels = c("Very Low Poverty","Low Poverty","Medium Poverty","High Poverty","Very High Poverty")

df$pov_cut = cut(df$pov,breaks = cut_breaks,labels = cut_labels, include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE)

df_povCutCount = aggregate(x = list(pov_cut_count = df$pov),
                           by = list(pov_cut = df$pov_cut, state = df$state),
                           FUN = "length")

head(df_povCutCount)
    
#               pov_cut state pov_cut_count
#    1 Very Low Poverty    CA             3
#    2      Low Poverty    CA             2
#    3   Medium Poverty    CA             1
#    4     High Poverty    CA             1
#    5 Very Low Poverty    TX             2
#    6      Low Poverty    TX             1
```

Comment: Thanks! When I use this code to the actual data and replace the column name, I get an error message ```Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I did not add `state = df$state` for the argument `by = list()` in function `aggregate()`, so I modified the answer. Maybe you could try replacing all arguments involve in `df$` by the actual variable names?